# Delete all child records from record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `teacher` that has a many-to-many relationship with `students`. Now, in the `Edit Teacher` method I want to first remove all the students he has, and then add the students that are selected.

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Teacher teacher, FormCollection form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        teacher.Students.Clear();

        var students = form["Students"];
        foreach (string id in students.Split(','))
        {
                teacher.Students.Add(db.Students.Find(int.Parse(id)));
        }

        db.Entry(teacher).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.saveChanges();
    }
}
```

Except the problem is, all the `Teacher-Student` relationships are not being removed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear() is not working as you think... EF is a bit pants when doing 'batch' delete... you have to iterate over them and remove one by one. e.g. You need something like...

```
foreach (var student in teacher.Students.ToList())
{
    db.Remove(student);
}
```

In this example you need ToList() to create a copy because most of the collection classes don't like it when you delete items from them during enumeration.

Edit: To get values / entities from database do something like

```
List<Students> students = (from stu in db.Students
                           where stu.TeacherId = teacher.Id
                           select stu).ToList();
```

Then iterate over these and remove as above, e.g.

```
foreach (var student in students)
{
    db.Remove(student);
}
```

Comment: But when I use debug mode, I can see that the teacher object has 0 students (I think because they are not loaded). How can I load the students and then remove them one by one?

Comment: You are probably clearing a copy and not the entity set itself.

Comment: But from your example, teacher.Students.ToList() is EMPTY, because it's model binded from the post parameters and not loaded from database. Then how should it be done?